# Iterator function miss-understanding concept

Tags: .net, vb.net, function, collections, iterator

If I'm not mistaken, an Iterator function serves as a way to build a collection faster because it remembers the index where the last item was added.

Now, is there a way to access the collection that is being build?

For example, lets say that I need to determine whether the collection contains an element before yield a new element, something like this (a very bad example):

```
Public Iterator Function MyFunc(Byval param1 As whatever) As IEnumerable(Of whatever)

    For value As Integer = 0 to whatever

        If Not THE_ITERATOR_COLLECTION.Contains(whatever)
           Yield value
        End If

    End For

End Function
```

Is this possible?

Comment: For your example you can use `Enumerable.Except` method.

Comment: Yes but you are telling me that I could use `Enumerable.Except` on the returned collection, but the function itself should avoid duplicates, not I manually after the collection is built. Anyways that is an example, there could be more reasons why I would like to have access to the collection that is being builded inside the function. thanks for comment

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. what is `THE_ITERATOR_COLLECTION`? If that is some collection with `Contains` method, your code should work apart from the typo(you used whatever in loop instead of value). Otherwise I don't get you. What is the question. What doesn't work?

Comment: You don't need to use `Except` outside of this method, inside this method itself you can consume the `Except` method. I'm missing what problem you're facing or what you don't know.

Comment: `THE_ITERATOR_COLLECTION` is the collection that returns the function by the `Yield` operator, by nature the collection of an `Iterator Function` (the return value) is not accesible (or that is what I'm asking to know) that's why I put `THE_ITERATOR_COLLECTION`  to denote its unknown name because I don't know how to have acces to the collection itself, `whatever` is whatever sort of irrelevant object for the example, just note this: `THE_ITERATOR_COLLECTION.Contains` .

Comment: `Inside this method itself you can consume the Except method.` How I could?.

Comment: I'm a c# guy. Apologizes for C# example. You could use   `var query = Enumerable.Range(0, whatever).Except(THE_ITERATOR_COLLECTION); foreach (var item in query) yield return item;`

Comment: iterator/yield differs from VBNEt to C#, maybe both we are miss-understanding important things. see, In VB.Net does not need to define/instance a collection inside the function to return a collection, the collection seems to be defined "hiddenly" when the `Iterator` keyword is set and only need to use `Yield` operator to add items on that "hidden" collection, then I'm asking how I could have acces to that `THE_ITERATOR_COLLECTION` "hidden" collection to use any `Enumerable` method on that collection like `Contains`, `Except` etc, or whatever on it, thanks for comment!

Comment: There is **no** hidden collection anywhere in both C# as well as VB. You need to understand how iterators work in first place. Jon's [article](http://csharpindepth.com/articles/chapter6/iteratorblockimplementation.aspx) is the most comprehensive resource.

Comment: ok see please, this is a very simple iterator function: http://pastebin.com/wY1nEnAV it builds a collection of integers, what I'm asking is: Inside the function block, how I could have acces to the collection? for access I'll mean have a reference to the collection itself to perform operations on it like for example `THE_COLLECTION.Except`.

Comment: (I made a type in the function I put `Yield 0` instead of `Yield x`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **No**, you cannot access the auto generated iterator at design-time.

The [Iterator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh156569.aspx) keyword offers a quick and easy way to create an iterator without actually having to create one. It's created by the compiler (based on the iterator function/property), thus not available at design-time. You've to either create a custom iterator or rethink you design.

Take a look at this simple iterator function.

```
Public Iterator Function Foo() As IEnumerable(Of Char)
    Yield "H"c
    Yield "E"c
    Yield "L"c
    Yield "L"c
    Yield "O"c
End Function
```

The above function is compiled into a function as seen below. The type of the auto generated iterator is named *VB$StateMachine_0_Foo*.

```
Public Function Foo() As IEnumerable(Of Char)
    Dim $sm As New VB$StateMachine_0_Foo
    $sm.$VB$Me = Me
    $sm.$State = -2
    Return $sm
End Function
```

There's nothing special about the inner workings of the iterator. It works the same way as any other well crafted iterator.

```
<CompilerGenerated> _
Private NotInheritable Class VB$StateMachine_0_Foo
    Implements IDisposable, IEnumerator, IEnumerator(Of Char), IEnumerable, IEnumerable(Of Char)

    <DebuggerNonUserCode> _
    Private Overrides Function GetEnumerator() As IEnumerator(Of Char) Implements IEnumerable(Of Char).GetEnumerator
        If ((Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId = Me.$InitialThreadId) AndAlso (Me.$State = -2)) Then
            Me.$State = -1
            Return Me
        End If
        Dim foo As New VB$StateMachine_0_Foo
        foo.$VB$Me = Me.$VB$Me
        Return foo
    End Function

    <DebuggerNonUserCode> _
    Private Overrides Function GetEnumerator0() As IEnumerator Implements IEnumerable.GetEnumerator
        Return Me.GetEnumerator
    End Function

    <CompilerGenerated> _
    Friend Overrides Function MoveNext() As Boolean Implements IEnumerator.MoveNext
        Dim VB$doFinallyBodies As Boolean = True
        Try
            Select Case Me.$State
                Case 0
                    If Not Me.$Disposing Then
                        GoTo Label_0066
                    End If
                    Return False
                Case 1
                    If Not Me.$Disposing Then
                        GoTo Label_0099
                    End If
                    Return False
                Case 2
                    If Not Me.$Disposing Then
                        GoTo Label_00CC
                    End If
                    Return False
                Case 3
                    If Not Me.$Disposing Then
                        GoTo Label_00F9
                    End If
                    Return False
                Case 4
                    If Not Me.$Disposing Then
                        GoTo Label_0126
                    End If
                    Return False
                Case 5
                    Exit Select
                Case Else
                    If Not Me.$Disposing Then
                        GoTo Label_0039
                    End If
                    Exit Select
            End Select
            Return False
Label_0039:
            Me.$Current = "H"c
            Me.$State = 0
            VB$ doFinallyBodies = False
            Return True
Label_0066:
            Me.$State = -1
            Me.$Current = "E"c
            Me.$State = 1
            VB$ doFinallyBodies = False
            Return True
Label_0099:
            Me.$State = -1
            Me.$Current = "L"c
            Me.$State = 2
            VB$ doFinallyBodies = False
            Return True
Label_00CC:
            Me.$State = -1
            Me.$Current = "L"c
            Me.$State = 3
            VB$ doFinallyBodies = False
            Return True
Label_00F9:
            Me.$State = -1
            Me.$Current = "O"c
            Me.$State = 4
            VB$ doFinallyBodies = False
            Return True
Label_0126:
            Me.$State = -1
        Catch exception1 As Exception
            ProjectData.SetProjectError(exception1)
            Dim $ex As Exception = exception1
            Me.$State = 5
            Throw
            ProjectData.ClearProjectError()
        End Try
        Me.$State = 5
        Return False
    End Function

    <DebuggerNonUserCode> _
    Private Overrides Sub System.Collections.IEnumerator.Reset() Implements IEnumerator.Reset
        Throw New NotSupportedException
    End Sub

    <DebuggerNonUserCode> _
    Private Overrides Sub System.IDisposable.Dispose() Implements IDisposable.Dispose
        Me.$Disposing = True
        Me.MoveNext()
        Me.$State = 5
    End Sub

    Private Overrides ReadOnly Property System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerator(Of Char).Current As Char
        <DebuggerNonUserCode> _
        Get
            Return Me.$Current
        End Get
    End Property

    Private Overrides ReadOnly Property System.Collections.IEnumerator.Current As Object
        <DebuggerNonUserCode> _
        Get
            Return Me.$Current
        End Get
    End Property

    Friend $Current As Char
    Friend $Disposing As Boolean
    Friend $InitialThreadId As Integer = Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId
    Friend $State As Integer = -1
    Friend $VB$Me As Form1

End Class
```

Related references:

- [Iterator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh156569.aspx)
- [IEnumerator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ienumerator(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [IEnumerator(Of T)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/78dfe2yb(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [IEnumerable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ienumerable(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [IEnumerable(Of T)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9eekhta0(v=vs.110).aspx)